# Flask WTForms - Can I define the placeholder for a field in the routes.py rather than the rendered template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, placeholder, wtforms

I currently have a working solution for making and populating a form that looks like the following snippets from my code:

forms.py

```
class TestPointForm(FlaskForm):
    injection_value = FloatField('Injection Value', render_kw={'class': 'form-control'})
```

routes.py

```
testpoint = TestPoint.query.first()
form = TestPointForm()
return render_template('testpoint.html', form=form, testpoint=testpoint)
```

testpoint.html

```
<div class="input-group">
    {% if testpoint.injection_value == None %}
    {{ form.injection_value(placeholder=testpoint.placeholder, value="") }}
    {% else %}
    {{ form.injection_value(placeholder=testpoint.placeholder, value=testpoint.injection_value) }}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

I have many fields like this and I want to clean up my template file by moving some of this pre-population of the form fields into my routes.py file. I've been able to pre-populate the value in some of my fields like `form.injection_value.data` but I haven't been able to pre-populate things such as the placeholder or data_value1 type fields. I've also tried adding a `pass` at the end of my `TestPointForm` to allow me to add some other dynamic fields but it didn't work for what I'm trying here.

I've tried a few unsuccessful methods in my routes.py file such as:

`form.injection_value.render_kw({'placeholder': testpoint.placeholder})`
`form.injection_value(placeholder=testpoint.placeholder)`

Is what I'm asking for possible? Worst case I could stick with all the if statements and field populating in my template file but I'd really like to avoid it if I can.

Comment: Why not set `default=''` on the field in the form definition?

Comment: The placeholder value is different for each instance of form generated. It's a calculated value for each of my testpoints so I can't add that into the form definition.